# Matlab incorrect sum value

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a vector `res` of size `1*10`.

Also, I have this code:

```
disp("Matrix:");
disp(res);
disp("Size:");
disp(size(res));
disp("Sum of elements:");
disp(sum(res));
```

Which outputs:

```
Matrix:
   1.0e+05 *

    1.9183    1.6247    1.5875    1.6979    1.3663    1.6511    1.5198    1.3014    1.2067    1.3661

Size:
     1    10

Sum of elements:
   1.5240e+06
```

**1.** What is `1.0e+05 *`?

**2.** How can the sum of `1.9183    1.6247    1.5875    1.6979    1.3663    1.6511    1.5198    1.3014    1.2067    1.3661` be `1.5240e+06`?

**What I did so far:**

I tried to see if there is a name conflict with `whos ('res')` but no other variable with the same name is in context.

I also tried to eliminate other `sum` name in context with `clear sum` but still I get the same result.

Comment: `1.0e+05` is scientific notation. The values of `res` are in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Here's your reference. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html

Comment: `format long g` may make you more conforatble maybe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Following notation:

```
Matrix:
1.0e+05 *

1.9183    1.6247    1.5875    1.6979    1.3663    1.6511    1.5198    1.3014    1.2067
```

means:

```
 Matrix:
191830    162470    158750    169790    136630    165110    151980    130140    120670
```

it is a scientific notation to show the result in a standard format. Therefore, the problem of summing is solved by this description.